# Sequelize & Express model & associate setup

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

### Background

I am working with Sequelize v4.2 and Express v4.15.2 and attempting to setup the models and associate them with one another. I have struggled to find any working v4.x Sequelize examples even after viewing this [Express/Sequelize tutorial](https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/task.js) as well as the [v4 migration docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html).

### Issue

Currently I am receiving the error below when trying to setup my initial models and associations.

```
/Users/james/Sites/awesome-app/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:80
    if (!target.prototype || !(target.prototype instanceof this.sequelize.Model)) {


TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/james/Sites/awesome-app/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/associations/mixin.js:80:16)
```

### Files/Code

My model setup file (`index.js`) looks like...

```
const fs        = require('fs');
const path      = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename  = path.basename(module.filename);
const env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config    = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
let db        = {};
let sequelize = undefined;

if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0) && (file !== 'index.js');
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ('associate' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And my first model (`address.js`) that fails looks like...

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Address = sequelize.define('Address', {
    street: DataTypes.STRING,
    city: DataTypes.STRING,
    state: DataTypes.STRING,
    zip: DataTypes.STRING,
  });

  Address.associate = function(models) {
    Address.belongsTo(models.attendeeGroup, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: {
        allowNull: false
      },
    });
  }

  return Address;
};
```

I am looking to setup my database tables and associate various models with one another. Is there another piece of setup I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My model I wanted to associate with was incorrectly named/capitalized. I had `Address.belongsTo(models.attendeeGroup, {` where `attendeeGroup` was camel case, but in fact it needed to be capitalized like `AttendeeGroup` which is the name of my other model.

My database was successfully created once I changed this model name.